# Struggling with implementing Abstract Factory pattern in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a program that is a homework assignment.  First we made a flight simulation, where we parsed xml files to load airplanes, cities, and flights.  All the planes have things like cruise speeds, cruise altitudes etc.  Each flight had a start time.  We created a timer function and kept track of time to see when to make a plane take off and land.

Now, the instructor has asked us to implement the abstract factory pattern for creating the airplanes, and I generally understand how it works...but I can't seem to implement it.

Also, the instructor has told us to implement the factories as singletons.

What I don't understand is this:

1. Where would I instantiate the factories?  I have a loader that loads data from the xml to a container class.  I assume I want to create one factory at a time, then get all airplanes of that type from the xml...and do that for all factories.
2. Since there is really no difference in different 'TYPES' of planes, what the heck kind of method interface would I make other than just creating the objects outright?

Here is some sample code:

Example of an XML aircraft

```
<PLANE>
        <MAKE>
            Gulfstream 150
        </MAKE>
        <TYPE>
            BUSINESSJET
        </TYPE>
        <DESCRIPTION>
            Business Jet
        </DESCRIPTION>
        <RATEOFCLIMB>
            1500
        </RATEOFCLIMB>
        <WINGSPAN>
            55
        </WINGSPAN>
        <LENGTH>
            56
        </LENGTH>
        <CRUISESPEED>
            528
        </CRUISESPEED>
        <CRUISEALTITUDE>
            41000
        </CRUISEALTITUDE>
    </PLANE>
```

The enum to use for types

`enum AircraftType {NOTYPE, PASSENGERJET, BUSINESSJET, SINGLEENGINE};`

The aircraft class:

```
class Aircraft
{
private:
    char make[32];
    char model[32];
    double cruiseSpeed;
    double cruiseAltitude;
    double climbRate;
    double wingspan;
    double fuselageLength;

public:

    Aircraft(void);
    Aircraft(AircraftFactory*);
    ~Aircraft(void);    
};
```

Abstract Factory class

```
class AircraftFactory
{

public:
    AircraftFactory();
    ~AircraftFactory();
};
```

Two subclasses for example

```
class BusinessJetFactory: public AircraftFactory
{
private:
    BusinessJetFactory();

public:
    ~BusinessJetFactory();
    static BusinessJetFactory* getInstance();
};

class PassengerJetFactory: public AircraftFactory
{

private: 
    PassengerJetFactory();

public:
    ~PassengerJetFactory();
    static PassengerJetFactory* getInstance();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a factory is used because you have a map that can match between a string (holding a type name or type id) -which is a string you find in your data source-, and a C++ type. You hardcode this correspondance in the main function at the initialization moment of your factory. You use one "abstract" base factory class, and one template factory that derives from the base one. The global (singleton) container, is just the map of factories (bind strings to factories) and this is where the hardcoding matters, you will instantiate (C++ term for "realizing a concrete class from a template") a factory for each necessary types. One factory has a `make` function that just returns a `T*` (with `T` the template type of the factory, and coincidentally the type of the objects it can create). All those factories are stored in the map, which is then known as a polymorphic container. the make function being virtual, the map contains only pointers to the base factory, but since the actual objects contained in there each knows its true `make` function (through virtual table) when you call `auto newobject = factorymap["passenger"]->make()` you get a new instance of the type that you specified in your hardcoded init of the factory that is in the "value" (side of the key_value) of the map for this element.

Now the exercice seems ill suited for that, because like you said, there is only one type of planes, so you need no factory whatsoever. Except if your xml holds something else than planes, like airports, passengers, runways, control towers, airline companies...

Comment: The xml holds flights and cities, also.  So in the previous program.  I created 3 vector containers.  One for airplanes, cities, and flights.  The flights hold information on when to takeoff, and which plane/departure/destination to link the flight to.  But I'm still not grasping why an abstract factory is good here.

Comment: @user2079828: Oh then yes, it is good. Because you have planes, cities and flights. Perfect case. You need to instantiate one factory for each of those types. But not like you did in your question, there is no specialized factory for business jets and passenjer jets. Only one for planes, and one for cities, and one for flights. That makes 1 abstract factory class, and 3 concrete factories that you "create" (via template instanciation) in the init function.

Comment: What you are saying does not mesh with my requirements.  Hereis the directive:               

Creation of aircraft must be separated and handled by subclasses of an AircraftFactory class following the Abstract Factory Design Pattern. There will be three subclasses of AircraftFactory, one each for creating passenger jets, business jets, and single-engine planes. The factories will create the appropriate type of aircraft, set the appropriate values for all parameters for the type of aircraft it creates. Each factory will return pointers to Aircraft objects.

Comment: That is kind of idiotic when the difference between these types is the value of an enumeration. This value has to be handled by a `.Parse(xmldocument&)` method that will map the xml name to the C++ corresponding enumerator and initialize other fields. (using tinyxml or rapidXML, or Xerces or even MSXML...). This Parse method exists in the Aircraft class not the factory. Re-read the requirements of the teacher, if you're sure of what you just said, you need to talk with your teacher.

Comment: I will.  The directive I gave you was quoted from the assignment...so yes that is correct.  Every plane has the exact same fields...just different numbers for each field etc....  The enumeration is used in his parsing class, which parses the xml...all we do is take that data, create the correct type of plane(I assume) based on the enumeration and load it.

Comment: Ok, that will definitely need a discussion :) and to feed that discussion, please talk to him about the [SOLID](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SOLIDPrinciples.aspx) principles. Notably `interface seggregation`, and `liskov substitution` because multiplyng types will cause `bloat`. Code is not designed like a relationale database, it has to be kept reasonable. To me here we have an un-necessary explosion of types (plane types, and/or factory types, when only 1 of each is needed).